# isset($array[$key]) does not response correct value

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am trying to check if an array key exits or not on php 7.1
You can see that there is an array key (1601851500000) in $db.
It must not enter into if case but it enters into it. This code was working good on ubuntu 18 server. Now its not running on ubuntu 20.  What's the problem?

```
echo var_dump(isset($db[$openTime]));

if(!isset($db[$openTime])){
  echo "insert: ".$openTime."<br>";
}

print_r($db)
```

output:

```
bool(false)
insert: 1601851500000
Array
(
    [1601851500000] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 500
            [pair] => KAVAUSDT
            [period] => 15m
            [chart_key] => 1601851500000
            [price_open] => 2.02900000
            [price_high] => 2.04500000
            [price_low] => 2.02900000
            [price_close] => 2.04500000
            [open_time] => 1601851500000
            [close_time] => 1601852399999
            [total_volume] => 4547.28019900
        )
)
```

Comment: Wouldn't architecture (PHP_INT_SIZE) be more relevant than version numbers here?

Comment: What is the value of `$openTime`?

Comment: @WesleySmith  $openTime = 1601851500000

Comment: @WesleySmith thank you so much. I found the answer which you share the link.